# Calculate in Pandas the difference between 2 Datetimes on Join between 2 Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've joined `2` dataframes and I also would like to calculate on join the difference
between the timestamp from the second DF with the timestamp from the 1st DF.

Here's the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

EMPLOYEES = "------------------";
CLIENTS = "------------------";
employeesDF = pd.read_csv(EMPLOYEES)
employeesDF = employeesDF[['personId','creationDate']]

clientsDF = pd.read_csv(CLIENTS);
clientsDF = clientsDF[['personId','creationDate']]

# how
final = employeesDF.merge(clientsDF, on="personId", how='inner')
```

How can we also calculate the difference between `creationDate` of the 1st DF and `creationDate` of the 2nd DF ?

**Sample Data**

```
personId,creationDate_x,creationDate_y, Difference <<<<---- Missing
XFJDSHKJDSS1213,2022-03-06 07:38:51.684+00,2022-03-06 07:39:56.966+00
DKJFKJKDSFJ3332,2022-03-06 07:38:51.684+00,2022-03-06 07:40:56.966+00
```

Comment: Do you need difference in both columns?

Comment: @jezrael: No , I want the difference in a new column between both of the DateTimes.

Comment: hmmm, can you add some sample data and expected ouput?

Comment: @jezrael: Updated post.

Comment: thinking solution in dupe not working? It should be.